# Does such a metric exist?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Does a metric $d: (-1,1) \times (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}_+$ exist such that the open interval $(-1,1)$ is complete (with respect to $d$) and that $d$ is equivalent to the usual Euclidean metric, $d_u$?

---

I'm having trouble figuring this out. First I thought that such a metric couldn't exist. I figured maybe we could define some function $f:((-1,1),d) \to (\mathbb{R}, d_u)$ and then try a cauchy sequence or something, but I really have no idea.. to add to all of this there are people saying that such a metric does indeed exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed such a metric, and you're on the right track thinking about ways to translate from $(-1, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. HINT: think about the function $\arctan x$ . . .

Comment: @Yoffa Well, $\arctan$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(-{\pi\over 2}, {\pi\over 2})$ . . .

Comment: @Yoffa It **does** mean that $(-1, 1)$ is complete, *under the right metric*.  (And continuity of $f$ isn't even needed here!) The point is that $f$ (or rather, ${2\over \pi}f$ lets you port the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ over to $(-1, 1)$: let $d(x, y)=d_{Euc}(f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(y))$. Can you show that $d$ is indeed a metric, and is complete?

Comment: More generally, given a metric space $(d, X)$ and a bijection $f:X\rightarrow Y$, we get an induced metric $d_f$ on $Y$, and $(d, X)$ and $(d_f, Y)$ are isometric (hence if one is complete, so is the other, and so forth).